# How do i add a day to the current DateTime.Now and then remove back one day?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

First im doing:
In top of Form1:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool SetLocalTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct SYSTEMTIME
        {
            public ushort wYear;
            public ushort wMonth;
            public ushort wDayOfWeek;    // ignored for the SetLocalTime function
            public ushort wDay;
            public ushort wHour;
            public ushort wMinute;
            public ushort wSecond;
            public ushort wMilliseconds;
        }

        private int day;
        private int month;
        private int year;
        private int hour;
        private int minute;
```

Then i have two method one to move the time in the system one day ahead and one method to move the time back to the current day one day back:

```
private void ChangeTimeForword()
        {
            dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            day = dt.Day;
            month = dt.Month;
            year = dt.Year;
            hour = dt.Hour;
            minute = dt.Minute;
            SYSTEMTIME time = new SYSTEMTIME();
            time.wDay = (ushort)day;
            time.wMonth = (ushort)month;
            time.wYear = (ushort)year;
            time.wHour = (ushort)hour;
            time.wMinute = (ushort)minute;

            if (!SetLocalTime(ref time))
            {
                // The native function call failed, so throw an exception
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
        }


private void ChangeTimeOriginal()
        {
            try
            {
                dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                day = dt.Day;
                month = dt.Month;
                year = dt.Year;
                hour = dt.Hour;
                minute = dt.Minute;
                SYSTEMTIME time = new SYSTEMTIME();
                time.wDay = (ushort)day;
                time.wMonth = (ushort)month;
                time.wYear = (ushort)year;
                time.wHour = (ushort)hour;
                time.wMinute = (ushort)minute;

                if (!SetLocalTime(ref time))
                {
                    // The native function call failed, so throw an exception
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + err.ToString());
            }
        }
```

So for the first time it worked but then the date was changed.
First the date was 9/30/2013 7:43PM
Then it changed now to the date: 6/11/2013 and it's moving between the 6/12 and 6/11

Strange. Why is that ?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` can't be changed by your code.  Can you provide a complete reproduction that demonstrates your issue?  It's possible the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Please change `DateTime.Now` in your sample to something like `new DateTime(2013, 11, 6)` and show what you get and expect.

Comment: Changed my question added the full code im using. My goal is to change the operation system/pc time and date one day ahaead and then one day back.

Comment: According to the MSDN documentation, is it possible that you can only do the operation once because you will lose permissions afterwards? Pasted: The calling process must have the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege. This privilege is disabled by default. The SetLocalTime function enables the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege before changing the local time and disables the privilege before returning.

Comment: I find this a little hard to believe. To convince me could you supply an SSCCE.